# Wrong indexing for sectionIndexTitlesForTableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I am using a list that can be sorted in various ways, regenerating the UITableView each time the sort-order is changed.

I set the sectionIndex each time the same way, which is:

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"•", @"•", @"•", @"•", @"•", @"•", @"•", @"•", @"•", @"•", nil];
}
```

Trouble is that when after I change the sort order (lets say from country to city name), the index doesn't work properly anymore.

It almost seems that the index doesn't recognize that the tableview has a different number of sections.

Any ideas where I might find the right screw for this?

Cheers

Comment: are you implementing `tableView:sectionForSectionIndexTitle:atIndex`? can you provide the code?

Comment: na, not implemented, but reading up on it it may hold the clue ... 'll give it a try ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Sergio's comment:

- are you implementing `tableView:sectionForSectionIndexTitle:atIndex` ?

That did it ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this logic in your code.

```
NSInteger section = [IndexPath section];

if (section ==0)
    // return sorted array for that section (1st section)

if (section ==1)
    // return sorted array for that section (2nd section)
```